# Why am I getting an undefined method error when I try to subscribe an email with the Mailchimp v2 API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp

In my Rails app, I'm attaching a callback to my User model that subscribes an email address to a Mailchimp list after it is created.

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  after_create :add_to_mailchimp_list

  protected

  def add_to_mailchimp_list
    @mc = Mailchimp::API.new('[Key Placeholder]')
    @mc.lists.subscribe(LIST_ID, example@example.com)
  end
end
```

However, Rails throws a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'subscribe'` exception? Any help?

Comment: What gem are you using?

Comment: Mailchimp's official generated API

Comment: I'd recommend removing the API key from your example code if that's your actual one, unchanged.